# Issue with assetic that

Tags: symfony, assetic

Has anyone seen this error in assetic,

```
/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/sass (LoadError)
```

I have got both ruby and sass installed  but keep on running into this error every time I dump assetic,

```
sudo app/console assetic:dump
```

Comment: And have you also verified that ruby and sass are located in /usr/bin/ruby and /usr/bin/sass, respectively? They could be installed in a different directory, for instance the sass executable is in /usr/local/bin/sass on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Assetic SassFilter automatically merges ruby and sass paths if both are set. Assetic has default values for ruby and for sass so both ARE set.

This makes a command like `/usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/sass some.css some.sass` which is wrong because it calls `ruby` bin with `sass` bin as argument. Since `sass` is installed as global gem with own binary file we don't have to call `ruby` before.

If you don't use `ruby` anywhere else in project you can fix this with:

```
assetic:
    ruby: ~
```

It will set null to Ruby binary so Assetic SassFilter will call only `sass` binary itself.